# Move on after passing command in windows python

Tags: python

Below is a function I am using.  When I call the command the spawn a putty session, it completely freezes up my gui program until I close the putty session. Is there any way to get around this, so that it calls the to the command, and then just moves along? (there is more I am passing to the command, but I have removed it to clean it up.

```
def SpawnSessionrmt(self,event):
    if "SSH" in self.protormt:
        subprocess.call('C:/bin/putty.exe ',shell=True)
    elif "RDP" in self.protormt:
        subprocess.call('C:/bin/rdp.exe)
    else:
        print "Not that you will see this...but that isn't a valid protocol"
```

Comment: try using subprocess.Popen instead :)

Comment: Is there a reason you're using `shell=True` in the first one? Or that you're adding a blank space to the end of the command name? (Luckily, that will happen to work on Windows with `shell=True`… but that certainly isn't something you should rely on.)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that, as [the docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.call) say, `call` will:

> Run the command described by args. Wait for command to complete, then return the returncode attribute.

If you don't want to wait for the command to complete, don't use `call`. Just create a `Popen` instance (and, ideally, `wait` for it later on, maybe at exit time, or in a background thread).

For example:

```
def SpawnSessionrmt(self,event):
    if "SSH" in self.protormt:
        self.children.append(subprocess.Popen('C:/bin/putty.exe ',shell=True))
    elif "RDP" in self.protormt:
        self.children.append(subprocess.Popen('C:/bin/rdp.exe'))
    else:
        print "Not that you will see this...but that isn't a valid protocol"

def WaitForChildren(self):
    for child in self.children:
        child.wait()
```

---

For a GUI app, I think the simplest thing to do might be to just put the `subprocess.call` into a background thread. That way, you can update the GUI when the actual work is done.

Unfortunately, each GUI framework has a different way of doing that—some let you do GUI stuff from any thread, some have a `run_on_main_thread` function, some let you post events to the main thread to be picked up by its event loop, some require you to build your own inter-thread communication system, etc. And you didn't tell us which GUI framework you're using.

So, here's an example with one framework I picked at random, `wx`:

```
def SpawnSessionrmt(self,event):
    if "SSH" in self.protormt:
        cmd = 'C:/bin/putty.exe'
    elif "RDP" in self.protormt:
        cmd = 'C:/bin/rdp.exe'
    else:
        print "Not that you will see this...but that isn't a valid protocol" 
        return
    def background_function():
        result = subprocess.call(cmd)
        event = wx.CommandEvent(MY_UPDATE_ID)
        event.SetInt(result)
        self.GetEventHandler().AddPendingEvent(event)
    t = threading.Thread(target=background_function)   
    t.daemon = True
    t.start()
```

(PS, I hate my random number generator, because I hate `wx`… but at least it didn't pick `Tkinter`, which would have forced me to write my own cross-thread communication around a `Queue` or `Condition`…)